# Why does sencha generated app for extJS not show Nav and Tab controls?

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I am working my way through the Getting Started tutorial for extJS at:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/getting_started/getting_started.html

I ran these commands:
sencha generate app -ext MyApp ./app
    cd app
    sencha app watch

I figured out I need to type "sencha web start" instead of "sencha app watch".

Now I go to

```
http://localhost:1841/
```

I can see the text on the left and on the right.
The left text is supposed to be in a Nav UI control.
The right is supposed to be in a Tab control.
But its just text. No UI.

What went wrong?

I can see folder structure and the ext framework it put there.
But it is just not rendering.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens when you are not in the application folder. 
As per the tutorial you listed, you must have executed the following command :

```
sencha -sdk /ext-5.1.1 generate app MyApp ./app
```

While executing the **sencha app watch** command, we have to be in the "app" folder.

**Points to keep in mind:**

while executing the watch command you should get an output :

```
[INF] Starting web server at : http://localhost:1841
[INF] ------------------------------------------------------------------
[INF] Waiting for changes...
```

If this is not displayed, execute the below command:

```
sencha -d app build
```

This will give the entire log which will help in debugging the issue

Hope this helps.